# Need to show help button on title bar of dashlet in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Even if I use following line on FTL file:

```
new Alfresco.widget.DashletTitleBarActions("args.htmlid")
.setOptions({"actions":[{"bubbleOnClick":
{"message":'${msg("dashlet.help")}'},"cssClass":"help","tooltip":'${msg("dashlet.help.tooltip")}'}]});
```

It can not show help button on title bar. Please tell me how to show "help" with  tool tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may this works for you

```
new Alfresco.widget.DashletTitleBarActions("${id}").setOptions(
   {
      actions:
      [
         {
            cssClass: "help",
            bubbleOnClick:
            {
               message: "Information about dashlet"
            },
            tooltip: "Display help for this dashlet"
         }
      ]
   });
```

Also add `<#assign id = args.htmlid?js_string>` at start of your ftl or change `"${id}"` to `"${args.htmlid}"` in above code.

Comment: thanks NaMaN,   i also used your code on FTL file , but it is not working , i can not see any help(?) button. have you any working code sample? if yes , please send it to me. i spend two days to find solutions :(  .

Comment: I can not provide you code sample as it's our project code but mean while you can refer to *my-tasks.get.html.ftl* located in  Alfresco installation directory \tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\dashlets also see updated answer